# Android Getting value from an Integer arraylist becomes a number

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and from what I read here most of the question goes to Imageview setting image. Here is my problem same as ImageView errors
Ive created a arraylist of Integer because of some function needed Int List rather than String List. Basically like most of function I created it like this one

```
private ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void setPicture(Integer datanumber)
{
    if (datanumber>=10)
    {
         myArrayList.add(R.drawable.picture);
    }
    else{
        myArrayList.add(R.drawable.picture_gray);
    }
 ///and so on
}
```

Everything works fine until I found out that I cannot get this string ex "R.drawable.picture" using this code

```
 myArrayList.get(0).toString();
```

Instead it gives me random number that I cannot understand.
My question is how can I return it to default value(or the one that I add on my list)
Thank you for spending time reading my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't giving you a Random number. It is giving you the value of `R.drawable.picture`. All resources in `R.*.*`are referenced through numbers. This is evident if you take a look inside R.java, which shows something like:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int help=0x7f020000;
        public static final int ic_action_search=0x7f020001;
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020002;
        public static final int splash1=0x7f020003;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int userName=0x7f070002;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int splash=0x7f030003;
    }
    public static final class menu {
        public static final int action=0x7f060000;
        public static final int menu=0x7f060001;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
        public static final int create_user=0x7f040004;
        public static final int help=0x7f040001;
        public static final int image=0x7f040002;
        public static final int primarymodtext=0x7f040003;
    }
}
```

What you are getting is the int value `R.drawable.picture`. This is because when you're adding a value to the array list, you're passing in the int value stored in `R.drawable.picture`.

You can still use this integer value you get like you would use `R.drawable.picture`. Just pass it in normally.

Comment: How can I use it if I want to bind picture again to another Imageview?

Comment: And sir using toast to get the numbers, it doesnt match the values on my R which is 2130837535

Comment: That's correct. The value in your R file should be 0x7F02001F, which is 2130837535 in Hexadecimal. And if you want to use that image in an imageview, then simply call `setImageResource(2130837535);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.valueOf(myArrayList.get(0));`

instead of `myArrayList.get(0).toString();`